# Leaflet: how to set unclickable in Leaflet 1?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In Leaflet 0.7 this code made all linestrings unclickable:

```
var highlightLayer;
    function highlightFeature(e) {highlightLayer = e.target;
     if (e.target.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {highlightLayer.setStyle({clickable: false});
    }else...
```

This - clickable: false - does not works in Leaflet 1. How to make unclicklable linestrings now?

Answer (score 3):

In Leaflet 1.0.0, the `clickable` option was renamed into the more apt `interactive`.

A layer which has its `interactive` option set to `true` will react to all kinds of mouse/pointer events, not only clicks. If set to `false`, it will react to none.

If you check the current Leaflet documentation at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html , you'll see that most layers (including `L.Marker` and `L.Polyline` among others) have an `interactive` option. You'll find that in the "Options inherited from Interactive Layer" section.

Also note that `L.GridLayer` and `L.TileLayer` do *not* have that option, and cannot be made interactive.

Comment: Thanks. I changed code:
 if (e.target.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {highlightFeature.setStyle({interactive: false});

No change.

Comment: The `interactive` option can only be set at instantiation time, changing its value will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the `off()` function or the alias `removeEventListener()` (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#evented-off). This can remove all event listeners registered to click events i.e.:

```
highlightLayer.removeEventListener('click');
```

I just had a similar use case where I needed to prevent a popup from re-opening on click while it's actually open already. I wonder why this solution has never been suggested during the past four years.